# Modify message for a single player

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm writing a minecraft plugin that will notify someone when you mention his name in chat. He will receive a customized message where in the message his name is underlined and recoulerd. It will also play a music note.

I have this, but it will sent the message to everyone in the server:

```
@Override
public void onEnable()
{
    Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
}

@Override
public void onDisable()
{

}


 @EventHandler
 public void onChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent e)
 {
     for(Player on:Bukkit.getServer().getOnlinePlayers())
     {
         if(on.equals(e.getPlayer()))continue;


         if(e.getMessage().contains(on.getName()))
         {
             e.setMessage(e.getMessage().replaceAll(on.getName(), ChatColor.GREEN + "@" + ChatColor.UNDERLINE + on.getName()));
             on.playNote(on.getLocation(), Instrument.PIANO, Note.natural(1, Tone.A));
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply cancel the event, and then send a message to all players, sending one player a different, custom message.

For example:

```
Player ply = (player who's name is mentioned)
String message = "<message>"

on.playNote(on.getLocation(), Instrument.PIANO, Note.natural(1, Tone.A)); //send the player the music
String s = message.replaceAll(ply.getName(), ChatColor.GOLD + ChatColor.UNDERLINE + ply.getName()); //change format of player's name
ply.sendMessage(s); //send message to the player
```

So, your event could look like this:

```
@EventHandler
public void onChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent e){
  String message = e.getMessage(); //get the message

  e.setCancelled(true); //cancel the event, so no message is sent (yet)

  for(Player on : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()){ //loop threw all online players
    if(message.contains(on.getName())){ //check if the message contains the player's name
      String newMessage = message.replaceAll(on.getName(), ChatColor.BLUE + ChatColor.UNDERLINE + on.getName() + ChatColor.WHITE); //format the message
      //change ChatColor.BLUE + ChatColor.UNDERLINE to the formatting you want
      on.sendMessage(newMessage); //send the player the message
      on.playNote(on.getLocation(), Instrument.PIANO, Note.natural(1, Tone.A)); //send the player the music
    }
    else{
      on.sendMessage(message); //else send the player the regular message
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but it gives me an error on check if message contains name. I have failed to get the name of the user that was mentioned. can someone help me. it must be something really easy im looking over.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used Bukkit before, but as mentioned in [this tutorial](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Plugin_Tutorial#Writing_a_safe_onCommand), instead of `e.setMessage("")`, try and use `on.sendMessage("")`.

**Edit**: I've had a look at the source and [`AsyncPlayerChatEvent`](https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/event/player/AsyncPlayerChatEvent.java) implements [`Cancellable`](https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/event/Cancellable.java), so how about you try sending the message to each player individually and then cancelling the event at the end, so you don't duplicate the message being sent, like this:

```
@EventHandler
public void onChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent e)
{
    for(Player on:Bukkit.getServer().getOnlinePlayers())
    {
        if(on.equals(e.getPlayer()))continue;

        if(e.getMessage().contains(on.getName()))
        {
            on.sendMessage(e.getMessage().replaceAll(on.getName(), ChatColor.GREEN + "@" + ChatColor.UNDERLINE + on.getName()));
            on.playNote(on.getLocation(), Instrument.PIANO, Note.natural(1, Tone.A));
        }
        else
        {
            on.sendMessage(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    e.setCancelled(true);
}
```

Comment: Hey, I have tried that however it will just send a extra message to the user. it won't change the message it will just send a seperated one. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 1):

To send a message to a single player, you can use:

```
playerobject.sendMessage(ChatColor.YOURCOLOR+"MESSAGETEXT");
```

Here's an example:

```
Player pl = *where you get your player from*;
pl.sendMessage(CharColor.RED + "Hello, this text will be displayed on the Screen of 1 Player in red.")
```

Thats all you need to do to send a colored message to a player

Comment: aah sorry i understand how to do that. What im trying to accomplish is. One player gets a message like "hi daniel" and for the player daniel it's "hi @daniel" Daniel should not receive 2 messages just a customized one.

Comment: i searchd for my answer in google, i started today with programming minecraftplugs, but i am programming java for a while, so i am no newbi, just saying. What i would try in this case is to cancel the broadcast and send to every Player at the server a single message. would be a way. and you might should use something like @ in front of the name in the chat as a marker to make sure, that rlly daniel the player and not somebody other whose name is daniel was meant. i dont know if canceling the broadcast is possible, because i didnt tryed until yet